# log4j2 monthly log rollover

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I'm using Log4J 2.0 to create logs for a project that I'm doing.  The logs are small and I have a requirement to maintain them for 3 months.  I'd like to have the current month's log with 3 archives (each containing a month's worth of logs).

The problem that I need help with is configuring log4j to rotate the logs at the beginning of the month (or the end of the month).

Pretty much every thing that I've found researching this problem is for log4j 1.x and talks about a datePattern parameter that doesn't appear to exist in 2.0.

**Here's my log4j2.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="warn" name="NKMS" packages="">
    <appenders>
        <FastRollingFile name="LogFile" fileName="logs/Tier2HttpServer.log" filePattern="logs/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4"/>
        </FastRollingFile>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <logger name="mil.navy.nrl.itd.xml_filter" level="trace"/>
        <root level="trace">
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
            <appender-ref ref="LogFile"/>
        </root>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

I'm writing INFO and above to the log file and debug to the console (for now).  The files are written to just fine, but they appear to rollover daily (which appears to be the default).

I've tried changing the FastRollingFile:filePattern to "'.'yyyy-MM" but that causes weird things to happen (only a single entry is written to file and an archive is immediately created).

I downloaded the source for log4j-2.0-beta8 and the PatternProcessor parses a RolloverFrequency that contains the enum RolloverFrequency.MONTHLY, but there again, I can't figure out how to implement / use it.

As always, any assistance or advice that you can provide would be GREATLY APPRECIATED!

-Ace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have found a bug. I would expect the filePattern of `"logs/app-%d{yyyy-MM}.log.gz"` to give you what you're looking for.

To clarify my understanding of the problem: The initial log event immediately triggers a rollover (creating an archive file). Instead, it should collect log events into the log file and not roll over until the end/beginning of the month. Is that description correct? Is there any other issue in addition to this initial unnecessary rollover?

Could I ask you to raise a JIRA ticket for this? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2

Comment: That is correct.  An archive is immediately created.  In addition only a single entry is made into the newly created log and log collecting ceases.  If I restart the application, the same process is repeated.

Comment: JIRA ticket created.  My first one, so I hope I did it right.  :)  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-385

Comment: This is a Log4J 2.0 beta8 bug. The filePattern above should indeed cause the logs to rollover monthly.